# Show scrollbar in RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, richeditbox

I'm trying to set vertical scrollbar in RichEditBox always visible. It seems that `ScrollViewer` attached properties should do the trick, but nothing happens, scrollbar still invisible.

Here is markup:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
        <RichEditBox
                 Margin="10"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 PlaceholderText="Enter comments here"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Height="140"

                 ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

So, why does scrollbar is not showing up and how to make it visible?

Comment: If it doesn't show up unless something else happens (it shows up when you mouse over it), that's a reflection of how the control is designed.  Typically, in these situations, the answer is not to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the property values for the scroll viewer that lives *inside* the RichEditBox Template, but you are also surrounding the RichEditBox with another ScrollViewer.

You have two options:

1. Remove the surrounding scroll viewer and let the one in the RichEditBox template handle it (recommended unless you need to do something specific with your scroll viewer).
2. Move the properties to the surrounding ScrollViewer.

As shown here:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <RichEditBox
             Margin="10"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             PlaceholderText="Enter comments here"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Height="140"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```